# How do I delete virtual interface in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, ifconfig

`ip link` shows this:

```
[root@0-25-90-68-79-4a log]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:68:79:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 00:25:90:68:79:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: gre0: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
10: 35978f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br35978f0 state UP qlen 32
    link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: br35978f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Here, the interface **35978f0** is the virtual interface which is tied to the bridge **br 35978f0**. I've already done `ifconfig 35978f0 down` and `brctl delif br35978f0 35978f0`.

But how do I delete interface **35978f0**?

Comment: use ip link delete 35978f0

Answer (score 139):

You can use `sudo ip link delete br35978f0` to remove the interface (replacing `br35978f0` with the code for the interface you wish to delete, as needed).

Comment: After reboot, then the virtual bridges showed again, even with brctl commands. Then I found it is because docker network, after deletion by command `docker network delete <bridge name>`, two bridges disappeared after reboot. [https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/]

Comment: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Comment: sudo ip link delete 35978f0

Comment: @AlexJansen: I managed to delete the interface after reading [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558839/unable-to-delete-virtual-network-interface-on-linux): `sudo iw wlp3s0mon del`

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried:

`ifconfig 10:35978f0 down`

As the physical interface is `10` and the virtual aspect is after the colon `:`.

See also
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-to-remove-virtual-interfaces-or-network-aliases/